# Browse Home Intranet by Machine Names

Tags: linux, apache, ip-address

I have Apache2 running on one of my linux machines, and I often use it to browse a local website on that machine from other machines on my home network.

But I can only do so by accessing the server by IP address.

I would like to be able to access via hostname, or some other arbitrary, memorable string, but I can't figure out how to do this. My Netgear router has a section that lists MAC addresses, corresponding IP addresses (assigned by the router through DHCP) and a user-configurable device name. I thought this would map between the device name and IP address, but it doesn't; all attempts to load a webpage using the device name fail, although the page loads just fine if I provide the IP address directly.

How do I make this happen? I'm running Linux on the server machine.

Comment: I'd suggest to ask at superuser.com. Also check that your workstations have DNS server (check `/etc/resolv.conf`) pointing to your router.

Comment: Most of the time the device name is Just to aid you or they are provided by the dhcp client.  The DNS server on the router normally just forwards to your ISp provided DNS servers and may or may not do limited caching.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will need to run a name server on a machine on your network and make it auth for your local domain. Then adjust your Dhcp server to give out that server as the DNS server.  Or you coukd always modify your hosts file on your boxes to contain the name to ip mappings if you don't have a lot of hosts.